# iPad SDK: Embedded YouTube movie plays fullscreen version behind UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview, uiscrollview, youtube

I have a UIWebview within a UIScrollView. Within the webview I have an embedded YouTube movie. When I play the YouTube movie everything works fine, however, when I press the fullscreen button the movie starts playing behind the webview. Bringing the WebView to the front does not work, because I want the scrolling capabilities of the ScrollView to do horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Why do you have a webview inside a scrollview? A UIWebView implements its own scrolling behaviour. Plus, depending on how you wire up the delegates, you could get weird behaviour wrt the `UIScrollViewDelegate` which both UIWebView and UIScrollView implement. So if you tell both the scrollview and the webview that its delegate property should point at yourself (your controller), then each time the webview scrolls, it'll fire methods like `scrollViewDidScroll:` which will be the same method that gets fired when your scroll view scrolls and not the webview. Seems nasty to me.

Comment: What I want to achieve is that I can scroll horizontal trough different webviews (where every webview is a magazine page). The scrolling behavior of the webviews is disabled. So is there a way to do this better or can you tell me how I can get the YouTube movie to the foreground?

Answer (score 12):

Basically, you want to be able to detect when a movie starts playing fullscreen and arrange your views appropriately. Then, when the fullscreen playback ends you want to be able to get your views back to how they are.

The problem is there's no documented way to hook into or detect when a UIWebView triggers video playback in full screen.

I said 'documented way', because there are some notifications you can use to detect when a UIWebView triggers fullscreen playback. You can just listen out for them and rearrange your views accordingly. However, I don't necessarily recommend this, because they're undocumented and subject to change (in fact, they have a spelling mistake in them up until iOS 4.3, see answers below).

```
// For iOS 4.3 and above:
UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification
UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification   

// For iOS 4.2 and below:
UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullcreenNotification
UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullcreenNotification   // (note spelling mistake)
```

Finding these out was a bit of a pain - there are actually several more notifications that get triggered when a YouTube video in a UIWebView gets played back. To find them out you'll need to drop a breakpoint on all posting of notifications, and then manually inspect the memory locations of those notifications to figure out their string names. I don't actually think anyone has pulled these out before, because when I google them I get nothing. But they do work, promise!

I hope being able to  get notified when the fullscreen playback is entered/exited will be helpful, with the massive caveat that Apple could change this undocumented behavior at any time. Your app won't get rejected outright for using them (because you're not calling any undocumented methods), and I've used it in shipping apps. But it's still not the best idea in the world...may be the only option you have though.

Edit: To clarify, based off the comment below: they're not constants, so you'd need to put them in quotes if you were registered for notifications.

Comment: What do I have to #import to get them to work? I'm using Xcode 4 and i get a build error (Use of undeclared identifier)

Comment: You need to put them in quotes, they're not constants, as follows: `addObserver:self selector:@selector(someSelector) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullcreenNotification" object:nil]` - hope that helps!

Comment: Bernado has made a good catch - in 4.3 the notification names have changed and are now spelt correctly.

Answer (score 6):

For iOS 4.3+, Apple have changed the names of these notifications:
UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullcreenNotification now is UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification

UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullcreenNotification now is UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification

Please pay attention: The term "Fullcreen" has changed to "Fullscreen".

Thanks!

Comment: Nicely spotted - I've updated my answer to reference your correction.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to confirm that this works after playing around with it for awhile.  You can get direct access to the view that the video is playing in. This is a blocks method of registering for the notification and pulling out the pertinent views.

Notice: You will need to delay adding subviews and/or access Apple internal subviews to remove the navbar for further customization.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
    addObserverForName:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullcreenNotification" 
    object:nil 
    queue:nil
    usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note){
          MPMoviePlayerController *theMovieController = [note object];
          UIView *theDestinationVideoView = [[note userInfo] 
          objectForKey:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerFullscreenViewUserInfoKey"];
}];
```

Comment: I am not having any success getting this to work, the block never gets triggered, is this still valid in 4.0?

Comment: OK, seems that they have fixed their spelling error, it is now: UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification

Comment: Can I pause the video programmatically while video play in full screen in uiwebview ?